# Collecting List with a custom list Supplier?

Tags: java, generics, collections, java-stream

I'm writing a generic list converter and would like to collect the mapped results
with a supplied list. The `clazz` arguments is just a CustomClassList which extends `ArrayList<CustomClass>`.
I am getting a compile time error.Is there any way to achive it with generics?

```
protected <T, R, P extends List<? extends Serializable>>
void mapper(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper, List list, P clazz){
    final Supplier<P> p = () -> clazz;
    list.map(l -> mapper).collect(p::get);// compile error reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) C, T exist so that ? extends Serializable can be converted to T
}
```

Comment: Do you mean [p::get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html#get--)?

Comment: fixed the issue

Comment: `List list` is of row type, result of `list.map()...` is ignored and there's no `map()` method in the `List` interface. Did you implied `list.stream().map()...`? `collect(p::get)` is also incorrect (have a look at the signature of the `collect()` method). Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I recommend you show what you want to do using a loop and POJ (pre-java 8 constructs).  That would give everyone a better idea of your goal.  Include detailed explanations and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to convert a list of one type to another, you need to add stream handling, `Collectors.toCollection` and fix some of the generic types so that "list" and "clazz" match the generic parameters:

```
protected static <T, R, P extends List<R>>
void mapper(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper, List<T> list, P clazz){
    final Supplier<P> p = () -> clazz;
    list.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toCollection(p));
}
```

For example, the following converts a list of strings into another list of their respective lengths:

```
List<String> input = List.of("abc","defg");
ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();

mapper(s -> Integer.valueOf(s.length()), input, output);
// =>> output is [3, 4]
```